# viewmodel returns null on postback mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this problem with a viewmodel, when the view is posted I'm getting null values for all the properties.

I've researched a bit, I can see multiple ppl have this problem, I tried some of the solutions but none of them works for me.

This is what I have:

Viewmodel:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public projectEvent ProjectEvent { get; set; }
    public List<eventType> eventTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddEditEvent(int? id)
    {
        var eventViewModel = new EventViewModel();
        var projectEventModel = new projectEvent();
        if (id != null)
        {
            using (var db = new DBEntities())
            {
                projectEventModel = (from p in db.projectEvents
                                  where p.eventID == id
                                  select p).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        eventViewModel.ProjectEvent = projectEventModel;

        using (var db = new DBEntities())
        {
            eventViewModel.eventTypes = (from p in db.eventTypes
                          select p).ToList();
        }

        return View(eventViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEditEvent(EventViewModel projectEvent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new DBEntities())
            {
                db.projectEvents.AddOrUpdate(projectEvent);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Events");
    }
```

View:

```
@model TTB.ViewModels.EventViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Main.cshtml";
}

<h2>Add/Edit Event</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEditEvent", "Admin"))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectEvent.eventName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectEvent.eventName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Date</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectEvent.eventDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectEvent.eventDate)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Event Type</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(v => v.ProjectEvent.eventType, new SelectList(Model.eventTypes, "eventTypeID", "eventTypeName"), new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProjectEvent.eventID)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btnSaveEdit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

Rendered html output:

```
<form action="/Admin/AddEditEvent" method="post">    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The eventName field is required." id="ProjectEvent_eventName" name="ProjectEvent.eventName" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ProjectEvent.eventName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Date</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field eventDate must be a date." data-val-required="The eventDate field is required." id="ProjectEvent_eventDate" name="ProjectEvent.eventDate" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ProjectEvent.eventDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Event Type</label>
                <select class="form-control dropdown" id="ProjectEvent_eventType" name="ProjectEvent.eventType"><option value="1">movie</option>
</select>
            </div>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field eventID must be a number." data-val-required="The eventID field is required." id="ProjectEvent_eventID" name="ProjectEvent.eventID" type="hidden" value="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btnSaveEdit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where do you get nulls exactly?

Comment: for all the values when I click the submit button http://gyazo.com/3a64553c65846521c0971dda283ab001

Comment: did you try to use ProjectEvent model instead of EventViewModel in your post action?

Comment: in your drop-down, sholnd't the first parameter be  v => v.ProjectEvent.eventTypes instead of eventType ? in the view I mean  on line @Html.DropDownListFor as the selected value/s from dropdown should go to model property eventTypes ...

Comment: @tmg I need to do EventViewModel because I have a dropdownlist with eventtype values. If I post projectmodel only, that will not work for the dropdown.

Comment: you need to create a custom binding as the default one does not know how to transform eventName, eventDate and event type into a EventViewModel or you can just put all the fields on the EventViewModel and populate the ProjectEvent manualy.

Comment: What is the HTML rendered output for the `ProjectEvent` properties?

Comment: @DavidG Please check the question, I added rendered output. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because you have a property on your model called **projectEvent** and you refer to your model as **projectEvent** when it is passed back into the controller.

Change

```
public ActionResult AddEditEvent(EventViewModel projectEvent)
```

To

```
public ActionResult AddEditEvent(EventViewModel model)
```

(or another name of your choosing)

http://tech.pro/blog/1930/don-t-name-a-model-the-same-as-a-property-you-re-trying-bind-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.