# ASP.Net Post not working

Tags: asp.net, post, null

I have a Problem with my Edit method in my Controller. The answer parameter always stays null when submitting the edit form.

What can I do to get the SmallTalkAnswer in the edit method to write it back to the database?

The Controller contains the edit method as found in ms documentation:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(SmallTalkAnswer answer)
    {
        var a = ModelState.IsValid;
        _smallTalkAnswerRepository.Update(answer);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

The View is generated by visual studio:

```
@model ChatBotAdminCenter.Models.SmallTalkAnswer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SmallTalkAnswer</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartitionKey, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartitionKey, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartitionKey, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RowKey, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RowKey, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RowKey, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Timestamp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Timestamp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Timestamp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ETag, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ETag, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ETag, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class SmallTalkAnswer : TableEntity
    {
        public SmallTalkAnswer() { }
        public SmallTalkAnswer(string hash, string categoryId)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = hash;
            this.RowKey = categoryId;
        }

        public string Hash => PartitionKey;
        public string CategoryId => RowKey;
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you have model class named `Answer`? Have you tried to change argument name into other name than provided?

Comment: thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto - that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you've a property named `Answer` on your model:

```
public string Answer { get; set; }
```

And the action method argument name has similar name of property name defined above:

```
public ActionResult Edit(SmallTalkAnswer answer)
```

AFAIK, this setup may cause confusion on default model binder side when referred the model in POST action method, hence it contains null value.

Try changing argument name of viewmodel in POST action method into another name by your choice (e.g. `model` or `smallTalkAnswer`, just avoid reusing property name as viewmodel argument):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(SmallTalkAnswer model)
{
    // other stuff
    _smallTalkAnswerRepository.Update(model);
    // other stuff
}
```

Similar issue: [viewmodel returns null on postback mvc 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191691/viewmodel-returns-null-on-postback-mvc-5)